# How to start docker containers using shell commands in Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm trying to start two containers (each with different image) using Jenkins shell commands. I tried installing docker extension in Jenkins and/or setting docker in global configuration tools. I am also doing all this in a pipeline. After executing `docker run...` I'm getting `Docker: not found error` in Jenkins console output.

I am also having a hard time finding a guide on the internet that describes exactly what I wish to accomplish. If it is of any importance, I'm trying to start a Selenium Grid and a Selenium Chrome Node and then using maven (that is configured and works correctly) send a test suite on that node.

If u have any experience with something similiar to what I wish to accomplish, please share your thoughts as what the best approach is to this situation.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because docker images that you probably create within your pipeline cannot also run (become containers) within the pipeline environment, because that environment isn't designed to also host applications.

You need to find a hosting provider for your docker images (e.g. Azure or GCP). Once you set up the hosting part, you need to add a step to your pipeline to upload/push the image to that provider's docker registry or to the free public Docker Hub. Then, finally, add a step to your pipeline to send a command to your hosting, to download the image from whichever docker registry you chose, and to launch the image into a container (this last part of download and launch is covered by `docker run`). Only at that point you have a running app.

Good luck.

Somewhat relevant (maybe it'll help you understand how some of those things work):

Command `docker build` is comparable to the proces of producing an installer package such as MSI.

Docker image is comparable to an installation package (e.g. MSI).

Command `docker run` is comparable to running an installer package with the goal of installing an app. So, using same analogy, running an MSI installs an app.

Container is comparable to installed application. Just like an app, docker container can run or be in stopped state. This depends on the environment, which I referred to as "hosting" above.

Just like you can build an MSI package on one machine and run it on other machines, you build docker images on one machine (pipeline host, in your case), but you need to host them in environments that support that.

Comment: I have a docker installed on my windows machine and I want to start several containers on that machine using jenkins docker run commands. I will look into what info you provided later.

Comment: ok, what i described does not change. From the perspective of Jenkins, your docker instance (sitting on your Windows) is external system, and the 2 docker commands (build and run, or just run if the image is already available) are something Jenkins.has to communicate with over TCP (which might be abstracted away from you in a form of a pipeline task). Ok, sorry, I went off-topic, but it's all good info above 

Comment: perhaps it's a matter of adding docker to system PATH variable. does typing "docker" in CLI work anywhere or just at a particular path?